# How do Hurricanes Form?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, coriolis-effect

I'm an Undergraduate Physics Student and I just went down the rabbit hole of asking "What's the Physics of Hurricane Formation?" when I discovered a few things and came up with even more questions. If you can use analogies or examples to explain, that would be greatly appreciated.

As Feynman would try to do, I tried to explain the Physics of how hurricanes form to younger me. I found a lot of gaps in my knowledge. In particular, my questions are as follows:

- Why does low-pressure region draw moist air towards it? How does that intensify the Hurricane?
- Why does rising air leave a low-pressure region in its wake? Is this the eye of the hurricane?
- Why does the air from the high-pressure region try to "fill in" the low-pressure vacuum? Is it because nature abhors a vacuum?

**Note**: I understand that single questions are better than a few, but (1) I naturally had all these questions around the same time (i.e., my questions arise in groups, not in isolation) and (2) it's better to ask all my questions in one go rather than dividing them up between four or five questions.

Comment: If someone can explain the downvote, I can improve the question.

Comment: Single questions are better than multiple.  Yours are related, but some may be better as a separate one.

If you're asking for answers to the questions at the top, I'm not sure the conversation helps.  A statement of the question with any of your existing understanding or difficulties in understanding is easier to parse.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Thanks for the feedback. Should I remove the entire conversation? I think it adds context in regards to the type of answer I expect, as well as my knowledge gaps. I know single questions are better than multiple, but I don't want to ask five separate questions on Physics SE.

Comment: It does add context, but I first thought you were asking for feedback on the information in the conversation, not on the questions at the top.  It just takes more time to read than just stating your info.  I think the heat engine question is sufficiently different from the air pressure questions that asking it separately would be a good idea.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Alright, conversation's removed.

Comment: @BowlOfRed I see your point. However, asking the heat engine question separately would take away attention from this question, no?

Comment: Perhaps.  But there are many thousands of open questions on this site.  If appropriate, you could add a link from one to the other.  Lumped questions make answering tough.  You can only accept one answer, but quality answers may only address one of your questions.  Having separate questions separate works much better.

Comment: @BowlOfRed As per your suggestion, I created another question for the Carnot Cycle question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/666038/whats-the-relationship-between-the-carnot-cycle-and-hurricanes-and-more